# How to make public members of a class private?

Tags: c++, class, private-members

I'm brand new to programming (in general) and C++ (in particular).  I'm trying to take the following public member variables and make them private:

```
int *coeff;
int order;
```

Unfortunately, I'm seeing the following errors:

'Poly::coeff' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Poly'

and

'Poly::order' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Poly'

Here's my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Poly
{
public:

    int *coeff;
    int order;

    int getData();
    int display(int *coeff, int order);
    void addition(Poly P1, Poly P2);
    void subtraction (Poly P1, Poly P2);
    void multiplication (Poly P1, Poly P2);

//  ~Poly();
};

int Poly::display(int *coeff, int order)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = order; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << coeff[i] << "x^" << i;
        if ((i - 1) != -1)
        {
            cout << "+";
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}

int Poly::getData()
{
    int i;
    cout << "Please enter the order of the polynomial: ";
    cin >> order;
    coeff = new int[order + 1];
    for (i = order; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the coefficient of x^" << i << " :";
        cin >> coeff[i];
    }
    return 0;
}

void Poly::addition(Poly P1, Poly P2)
{
    int max;
    int i;
    max = (P1.order > P2.order) ? P1.order : P2.order;
    int *add = new int[max + 1];

    if (P1.order == P2.order)
    {
        for (i = P1.order; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            add[i] = P1.coeff[i] + P2.coeff[i];
        }
    }

    if (P1.order > P2.order)
    {
        for (i = P1.order; i > P2.order; i--)
        {
            add[i] = P1.coeff[i];
        }
        for (i = P2.order; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            add[i] = P1.coeff[i] + P2.coeff[i];
        }
    }

    if (P1.order < P2.order)
    {
        for (i = P2.order; i > P1.order; i--)
        {
            add[i] = P2.coeff[i];
        }
        for (i = P1.order; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            add[i] = P1.coeff[i] + P2.coeff[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "\nAddition:";
    display(add, max);
    cout << "\n";
}

void Poly::subtraction(Poly P1, Poly P2)
{
    int max;
    int i;
    max = (P1.order > P2.order) ? P1.order : P2.order;
    int *sub = new int[max + 1];

    if (P1.order == P2.order)
    {
        for (i = P1.order; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            sub[i] = P1.coeff[i] - P2.coeff[i];
        }
    }

    if (P1.order > P2.order)
    {
        for (i = P1.order; i > P2.order; i--)
        {
            sub[i] = P1.coeff[i];
        }
        for (i = P2.order; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            sub[i] = P1.coeff[i] - P2.coeff[i];
        }
    }

    if (P1.order < P2.order)
    {
        for (i = P2.order; i > P1.order; i--)
        {
            sub[i] = -P2.coeff[i];
        }
        for (i = P1.order; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            sub[i] = P1.coeff[i] - P2.coeff[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "\nSubtraction:";
    display(sub, max);
    cout << "\n";
}

void Poly::multiplication(Poly P1, Poly P2)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int max;

    max = P1.order + P2.order;
    int *mult = new int[max + 1];

    for (i = P1.order; i >= 0; i--)
    for (j = P2.order; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        mult[i + j] += P1.coeff[i] * P2.coeff[i];
    }
        cout << "\nMultiplication:";
        display(mult, max);
}



int main()
{
    int choice;
    Poly P1, P2, P3;
    cout << "-------- Instructions --------" << endl;

    cout << "For polynomial 1... " << endl;
    P1.getData();

    cout << endl;

    cout << "For polynomial 2... " << endl;
    P2.getData();

    while (1)
    {
        cout << "\n******** Menu Selection ********" << endl;
        cout << "1: Addition\n2: Subtraction\n3: Mutiplication\n0: Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter your choice (1, 2, 3 or 0):";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "\n-------- Addition --------\n";
            cout << "Polynomial 1: ";
            P1.display(P1.coeff, P1.order);
            cout << "Polynomial 2: ";
            P2.display(P2.coeff, P2.order);
            P3.addition(P1, P2);
            cout << "--------------------------\n";
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "\n------ Subtraction ------\n";
            cout << "Polynomial 1: ";
            P1.display(P1.coeff, P1.order);
            cout << "Polynomial 2: ";
            P2.display(P2.coeff, P2.order);
            P3.subtraction(P1, P2);
            cout << "--------------------------\n";
            break;

        case 3:
            cout << "\n------ Subtraction ------\n";
            cout << "Polynomial 1: ";
            P1.display(P1.coeff, P1.order);
            cout << "Polynomial 2: ";
            P2.display(P2.coeff, P2.order);
            P3.multiplication(P1, P2);
            cout << "--------------------------\n";
            break;

        case 0:
            cout << "The program will now terminate.  Thank you." << endl;
            exit(0);

        default:
            cout << endl;
            cout << "You have entered an invalid selection." << endl;
            cout << "Please enter a positive integer between 0 and 3.";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone offer guidance on how to best modify my code so that int *coeff and int order are private members?

Thanks very much in advance.
-Ryan

Comment: That's a lot of code for someone new to C++ ... maybe start with smaller programs.

Comment: Add member functions that allow access to the private data members. And your class needs to follow the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), or better, replace `int *coeff` with `std::vector<int> coeff`

Comment: You can do `private:` to make them private. The error messages suggested you already tried that , and the errors indicate that you are trying to access the private variables from outside of the class.  Also it is confusing to have your functions take parameters called `coeff` and `order` because in the function bodies, those names hide the class members. I suspect that what you want to do is to make `display` take no parameters, and change `P1.display(P1.coeff, P1.order);` to `P1.display()`

Answer (score 3):

The idea of making something `private` means you're *not* allowed to access outside of member or `friend` functions (that's the purpose of `private`). The code is failing in `main` at things like `P1.display(P1.coeff, P1.order)` because `main` isn't a member of the `Poly` class and, as such, is not *allowed* to access `Poly::coeff` or `Poly::order` (as the compiler is telling you).

I would suggest you change the definition of `Poly::display(int *coeff, int order)` to not require you pass in `coeff` and `order`, since the instance already knows what these values are. I would also take out the `return 0`, since it isn't buying you anything.

```
void Poly::display()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = order; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << coeff[i] << "x^" << i;
        if ((i - 1) != -1)
        {
            cout << "+";
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Inside that member function, the variables `order` and `coeff` are implicitly picking up the members of your class that were previously *shadowed* by the parameters you were passing.

Answer (score 2):

> "Can anyone offer guidance on how to best modify my code so that int *coeff and int order are private members?"

Your code in `main()`

```
P1.display(P1.coeff, P1.order);
```

still tries to access these now `private` class members directly, which won't work of course (that's why we make these members `private`).

For your case, you don't need to pass these variables as parameters to that function at all, since the actual values are available for the `P1` instance of `class Poly` already.

Change your member function signature to

```
int display();
```

and definition to

```
int Poly::display() {
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = order; i >= 0; i--) {
        cout << coeff[i] << "x^" << i;
        if ((i - 1) != -1) {
            cout << "+";
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Note that accessing `order` or `coeff` inside the `Poly::display()` member function, can be read as equivalent to `this->order` and `this->coeff`.

Class member functions can be considered to have a `this` pointer implicitly, and can access (`private`) class member variables directly, without need to specify these as parameters.

After changing the stuff as proposed above, you can just call

```
P1.display();
```

Change other signatures/access to `coeff`, `order` analogous.

---

**NOTE:**

There are more flaws in your class declarations. Something like

```
void addition(Poly P1, Poly P2);
```

won't work well. You want to operate with the actual instance as the left hand value, and the other as a constant right hand value. IMHO your member function should look like this

```
Poly& addition(const Poly& rhs) {
     // perform addition operations with this and rhs
     return *this;
}

Poly addition(const Poly& rhs) const {
     Poly result = *this;
     // perform addition operations with result and rhs
     return result;
}
```